# How to access nested array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have to access data from an API that is similar to:

```
{
 "speakers": [
   {
     "name": "speakerName",
     "profile_picture": "profilePic"
   }
 ]
},
{
 "speakers": []
}
```

I saved speakers as an array, but I am not sure how to access the objects inside the inner array. The speakers parameter gives the entire array (name and profile picture).

```
const PublicEventsInfo = ({speakers}) => { 
 
}
```

When I try the code below, I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined.

```
speakers[0].name
```

How would I access just the name portion of speakers inside PublicEventsInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Either `obj.key` or `obj[key]`. However, as you have an array you need to access it with a numerical index. So assuming you want the first in the array and there is always one in the array, you could do like this:

```
const test = {
 "speakers": [
   {
     "name": "speakerName",
     "profile_picture": "profilePic"
   }
 ]
}
const PublicEventsInfo = ({speakers}) => { 
 console.log(speakers[0].name)
}
PublicEventsInfo(test)
```

However, it looks like the data you provided has the incorrect structure:

```
{
 "speakers": [
   {
     "name": "speakerName",
     "profile_picture": "profilePic"
   }
 ]
},
{
 "speakers": []
}
```

This is not a valid json, unless wrapped in an array.

Comment: The Json is wrapped in an array. When I try to do console.log(speakers[0].name), I get an error of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name').

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly

You should just be able to do `const name = speakers.name`

Comment: the value of speakers is an array, so it would be `speakers[0].name`, assuming you want the first speakers name.

Comment: @wooooooo thank you for the clarification, I sometimes forget that about arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this? `data.map(x=>x.speakers).flat()` can do someting like `unwrap speakers and concat`

```js
let data = [{
    "speakers": [{
      "name": "speakerName",
      "profile_picture": "profilePic"
    }]
  },
  {
    "speakers": []
  }
]

const PublicEventsInfo = ({
  speakers
}) => {
  return <ul>{speakers.map((x,i)=><li key={i}>{x.name}:{x.profile_picture}</li>)}</ul>
}

export const Page=()=><PublicEventsInfo speakers={data.map(x=>x.speakers).flat()}>
```